# Obscure Dart syntax

Tags: dart

While working through the the [Dart Route library example for client side coding](https://github.com/dart-lang/route/blob/master/example/client.dart)  I came across this snippet.

```dart
 var router = new Router()
    ..addHandler(urls.one, showOne)
    ..addHandler(urls.two, showTwo)
    ..addHandler(urls.home, (_) => null)
    ..listen();
```

My question is how does `(_) => null` work?  It seems to specify a function that returns a null value but what does `(_)` mean?

Comment: This is required function argument. Argument named as "_" because it not used. This is the same "..addHandler(urls.home, (myUnusedArgumentThatINotWantUse) => null)". The "null" means that your function return null. This construction called "function expression". You construct function that has no statements. Or more correctly has just one statement called epression statement. In our case "null" are epression statement. This is short form of declaring functions that directly return expression. The "null" here also means "return null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try explain this by the example.

```dart
void main() {
  var helloFromTokyo = (name) => 'こんにちわ $name';
  var greet = new Greet();      
  greet.addGreet('London', helloFromLondon)
  ..addGreet('Tokyo', helloFromTokyo)  
  ..addGreet('Berlin', helloFromBerlin)
  ..addGreet('Mars', (_) => null)
  ..addGreet('Me', (name) => 'Privet, chuvak! You name is $name?')
  ..addGreet('Moon', null);

  greet.greet('Vasya Pupkin');
}

String helloFromLondon(String name) {
  return 'Hello, $name';
}

String helloFromBerlin(String name) {
  return 'Guten tag, $name';
}

class Greet {
  Map<String, Function> greets = new Map<String, Function>();

  Greet addGreet(String whence, String sayHello(String name)) {
    greets[whence] = sayHello;
    return this;
  }

  void greet(String name) {
    for(var whence in greets.keys) {
      var action = greets[whence];
      if(action == null) {
        print('From $whence: no reaction');
      } else {
        var result = action(name);
        if(result == null) {
          print('From $whence: silent');
        } else {
          print('From $whence: $result');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
From London: Hello, Vasya Pupkin
From Tokyo: こんにちわ Vasya Pupkin
From Berlin: Guten tag, Vasya Pupkin
From Mars: silent
From Me: Privet, chuvak! You name is Vasya Pupkin?
From Moon: no reaction
```

Comment: This is useful but I guess what I am asking is: Is `()` the shorthand for unnamed function with no parameters?

Comment: This answer on your main question "My question is how does (_) => null work? It seems to specify a function that returns a null value but what does (_) mean?"

Comment: One more tiny example that could be added would be `var helloFromTokyo = (name) => 'Konnichiwa $name';`. That way you could reference this anonymous function within the current function but not outside. As you (@Emmentaler) seem to be familiar with Java; it will almost look look the same in Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax

Comment: @KayZ Your example accepted as `var helloFromTokyo = (name) => 'こんにちわ $name';`.

Answer (score 7):

`(_)` means it is a function with one parameter but you don't care about that parameter, so it's just named `_`. You could also write `(ignoreMe) => null`. The important thing here is, that there needs to be a function that accepts one parameter. What you do with it, is your thing.

Comment: If `printNumber(number) => print('The number is $number.');` is the way in which the function would be declared in regular dart syntax shouldn't a function look like this `_(a)=>null`?

Comment: I should also ask would () be short-short hand for a function with no parameters?

Comment: Short hand for a function with no parameters "() => null" or for void function "() {}". But "(_) => null" is not a short-hand. Because this is the same as "(x) => null" and other options from the latin alphabet.  This is a `short form` of this "(x) { return null; }"

Answer (score 7):

`(_) => null` means : *a function that take one parameter named `_` and returning `null`*. It could be seen as a shortcut for `(iDontCareVariable) => null`.

A similar function with no parameter would be `() => null`.

A similar function with more parameters would be `(_, __, ___) => null`.

Note that `_` is not a special syntax defined at langauge level. It is just a variable name that can be used inside the function body. As example : `(_) => _`.

Comment: I have been avoiding the word 'anonymous' but maybe I should have used it in my question. Can the function have a name?  I know it might seem pointless to name a function whose name will never be used but the `()` seem a bad choice for indicating a function since parens are grouping operators that will probably conflict in more complex expressions.  Putting an identifier in front of the parens makes it easier to recognize from a compiler/interpreter perspective.

Comment: I just thought about it some more.  Technically, the complete expression is `()=>{expression}` not just `()`

Comment: If you define a function `returnNull(_) => null;` you can use it in `..addHandler(urls.home, returnNull)`